# Why are my VM's visible to either virsh virt-manager, but not both?

Tags: linux, xen, virsh

I have an **Ubuntu 14.04** host running **xen**, with a couple of **VM's** (`win7 and another 14.04`). I created these remotely using **virt-manager**. They've been running nicely for quite some time.

But when I try "`virsh list --all`" on the host, I get nothing in the list.

I attempted to import one of the VM's, like this:

```
virt-install -n my_name -r 512 --os-type=linux --os-variant=ubuntutrusty --disk /var/lib/libvirt/images/my_name.img --import
```

As far as **virsh** was concerned, this looked like it worked. It showed up as "**running**" on virsh list. However, **I couldn't connect to it**, not even ping it. Looking at **virt-manager**, it still thought the **VM was shut off**.

I ran "`virsh destroy my_name`" to halt it, then started it in **virt-manager**. It's running as normal there, but **virsh list shows as shut off**.

The two apps seem to be pulling from different sources to get their info, but I don't know where those are, and don't know how to get them to get along.

How do I get **virsh** and **virt-manager** to be friends?

Comment: Does `virsh uri` show the same connection URI as you see when you look at the connection details in virt-manager?

Comment: No, and now I understand a bit more about the connection URI's. By default, virsh was using qemu:///system, and I needed to change it to xen:///. Thank you.

Answer (score 15):

I posted an answer at [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/a/861853/300053) about this. Reproducing it here:

> Check the output of `virsh uri`. If it returns `qemu:///session`, but
>   you're using a `qemu:///system` connection in Virt-Manager, you found
>   the cause.
>
> In order to fix it, you should either create a "QEMU/KVM user session"
>   connection in virt-manager, or run `virsh define ~/.config/libvirt/qemu/<filename>.xml` **as root**. This will create
>   the xml definition under `/etc/libvirt/qemu` which will then be picked
>   up by virt-manager.

Comment: To add "QEMU/KVM user session" in virt-manager, click File > Add Connection..., under "Hypervisor" select "QEMU/KVM user session", check "Autoconnect", and click "Connect".

Answer (score 10):

Another way to change your connection URI and use qemu:///system as default is to edit your .bahsrc and add:

`export LIBVIRT_DEFAULT_URI="qemu:///system"`

logout and login again and virsh and virt-manager will be friends!

Answer (score 2):

You can connect to `qemu:///session` with the cmd:

> $> virt-manager -c qemu:///session

or

> $> virt-manager --connect=qemu:///session

Comment: Thank you this helped me a lot and led me in the right direction. Upvoted